# What happens to a User-ID in google analytics when the user clears the cookie?

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

I am trying to implement the user ID feature in Google Analytics to track user behaviour across devices. I know that the client ID gets cleared once the user clears the ga cookie.

What happens to the user ID in this case? Is it tied to the authentication system and hence not dependent on the cookie? Can someone throw some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate a unique user id for ervery user and store it.
Everytime the user logs in to you site, you have to set correct the user id.

Take a look to this document.
[Google Documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

The id that you will pass should be a unique id from your system that persists.

If the user clears their cookies, it will not matter because the user id will reset once they access a page next time.